# Should I use Multi Transaction Translator?

Tags: usb, hub

I'm designing a board which has two USB 2.0 Full-Speed (12 Mbps) USB-UART controller (CP2108). 
These controllers will be communicating with the PC via an USB2422 HUB. 
This hub has got a Single Transaction Translator, but it's cheap and doesn't need a lot of external components. 
I have a bit of doubt that this design will work properly with this hub. 
Is it possible that there will be communication and speed problems? Maybe I should use another hub which has multi Transaction Translator?

Comment: Which baud rates do you intend to run? Also, there are high speed capable quad-port USB2uart chips available.

Comment: I want to use 115200 on each UART. Yes, I know. I have used FT4232 in an another design, but now I can using only these.